# Prepositions in a compound sentence

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Following Martha's advise I am splitting up a question [Compound sentences, the punctuation and mooore](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/compound-sentences-the-punctuation-and-mooore).

Consider the following sentence:

> One of the items that needed a further development was a research on child nodes of a story representing its sub categories being updated the moment the list of sub categories is changed through edit page for stories.

Did I miss any prepositions obligatory for sentences that complex?

If you feel like it's not the right way to use English anyway, please see questions

[Constructing compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4421/constructing-compound-sentences)

and

[How to rephrase a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4429/how-to-rephrase-a-sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically this sentence parses. No missed prepositions. There are two indefinite articles that might be superfluous:

> One of the items that needed further development was research on child nodes...

And yes, I do think that this sentence needs rephrasing (rule of brevity). See my answers on the corresponding questions.

Comment: Well, I don't understand articles. So far I have only seen rules telling that an article in front of singular form of a noun is a must, unless you are talking about it in general.

Comment: @Eug In the case of 'research' above you aren't exactly referring to research as a thing, or a singular event, but rather as an on-going or collective activity. For 'development' you can get away with or without the article since you might have been referring to development as an activity [where you would delete] or development as a singular change [where you'd keep]. However, eliminating the article simplifies the lengthy opening clause.

Comment: @mfg: Thanks! I understand the rule, but I can't really feel what is an activity and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

> An item for further development is
>   research on [child nodes of a story (re-word?)]
>   that display sub-categories'
>   updates whenever the list of sub-categories is changed on the edit page
>   for stories.

As far as I can tell this might be a better phrased articulation of what you're saying. I take it to mean that:

- A list of X [subcategories] exists,
- Somewhere else, updates to X are displayed,
- Changes to X (or the list of x) are related to "child nodes"
- and More research is called for regarding that system (though I don't know what part needs research).

Here's another option for the front end:

> An item for further [research/development] is how [child nodes of a story (re-word?)]
>   display updates to the sub-categories whenever the list of sub-categories is changed on the edit page for stories.