# How can I rephrase compound sentences to make them simpler?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Following Martha's advise I am splitting up a question [Compound sentences, the punctuation and mooore](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/compound-sentences-the-punctuation-and-mooore).

Consider the following sentence:

> One of the items that needed a further development was a research on child nodes of a story representing its sub categories being updated the moment the list of sub categories is changed through edit page for stories.

While I indeed wanted to practice compound sentences (see a question [Constructing compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4421/constructing-compound-sentences)), another reason why this sentence is so complex is that I don't know how to split it into smaller parts.
Could you help me with it?

If you need the context please read a post from the second link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a native speaker, so there will sure be mistakes, but I would write:

> One of the items that needed more work was research on story child nodes updating. The child nodes represent story sub categories and should be automatically updated when the list of sub categories is changed on the story edit page.

Comment: This looks nice! Although I have doubts about the expression "story child nodes updating". It lacks of prepositions for sure in my opinion. But the second sentence is perfect!

Comment: @Eugene, what do you mean here by 'research' and 'story'?  I'm guessing synonyms would make more sense there, but I don't know which to go for without more information.

Comment: @Ophiuroid: The research here is just a process of investigation on something. A story is a term from a domain model, which should not be substituted with a synonym.

Comment: @Ophiuroid: Could you please explain why the noun research doesn't have to be preceded with an article?

Comment: @Eugene Strizhok: In that case, if something needs more work, isn't it clear that it needs more investigation?  The sentence could be simplified to "One of the items that needed more work was the updating of story child-nodes."

Comment: @Eugene Strizhok: You can say "a research paper" or "a research project," but research used as a noun very rarely takes an indefinite article.

Comment: @Ophiuroid: I think a sentence written your way suggests that we had been working on getting child nodes updating. But we didn't. Not as such. The difference can be explained this way: child nodes would still be unupdatable after research is complete, but we would know whether it is possible at all, and in case it is, what it would take us to get them updatable.

Answer (score 2):

An answer is already accepted, but let me try:

> One item that needed further development was updating the child nodes of a story. These nodes, representing the story's subcategories, must be updated the moment the list of subcategories is changed via the edit page for stories.

Comment: Nicely phrased! I would replace "must" with "should" though.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it a try:

> One of the items that needed further development was research on child node behavior.
>
> Child nodes are defined as follows: a story has sub-categories, and these categories are displayed as child nodes.
>
> Should these child nodes get updated when the list of subcategories is changed?
>
> Should this happen whenever a story is changed using the Edit page?

Or even:

> I needed to further research child node update behavior.
>
> Child nodes are used to display the subcategories of a story.
>
> Should they be updated whenever the list of subcategories changes as a story is edited using the Edit page?

Or maybe you want to express this:

> I needed to further research child node update behavior.
>
> Child nodes are used to display the subcategories of a story.
>
> My question was: should they be updated whenever the list of subcategories changes as a story is edited using the Edit page?

Comment: No, I don't think any of these convey the meaning correctly. By this sentence I wanted to remind of research and to recall its purpose. It in no way means that the described update mechanism exist. So I can't see why you are talking about it in the Present Simple.

Comment: @Eugene - OK, so there is hidden meaning in your sentence that is not clearly conveyed. I try to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> One of the underdeveloped items involves child nodes of a story, which represent sub categories that are updated when their list is changed through edit page for stories.